# Variation in the data

Tags: r, dataframe

Based on Id, I would like to measure the variation between the beginning and the end of a weekday. For example, how does Mon_start and Mond_End vary in Id 11 and Id 12. I was thinking to create boxplots?  What is the best way to do this in R?

Data structure:

[image]

Sample data with several cases:

```
df<-structure(list(Id = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15), number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), start.end = c("Mo_start", "Mo_end", 
"Tue_start", "Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", 
"Thur_end", "Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Mo_start", "Mo_end", "Tue_start", 
"Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", "Thur_end", 
"Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Mo_start", "Mo_end", "Tue_start", "Tue_end", 
"Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", "Thur_end", "Fri_start", 
"Fri_end", "Mo_start", "Mo_end", "Tue_start", "Tue_end", "Wed_start", 
"Wed_end", "Thur_start", "Thur_end", "Fri_start", "Fri_end", 
"Mo_start", "Mo_end", "Tue_start", "Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_end", 
"Thur_start", "Thur_end", "Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Mo_start", 
"Mo_end", "Tue_start", "Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", 
"Thur_end", "Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Mo_start", "Mo_end", "Tue_start", 
"Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", "Thur_end", 
"Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Mo_start", "Mo_end", "Tue_start", "Tue_end", 
"Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", "Thur_end", "Fri_start", 
"Fri_end"), time = c("0", "0", "07:00", "14:45", "07:00", "14:45", 
"07:00", "14:45", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "07:00", "15:15", 
"07:00", "14:45", "0", "0", "08:00", "15:45", "08:00", "15:45", 
"08:00", "15:45", "08:00", "15:45", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "09:00", "15:45", "0", "0", "0", "0", "07:00", "17:15", 
"06:00", "16:45", "07:00", "17:00", "07:00", "17:15", "07:00", 
"17:45", "09:45", "14:45", "06:30", "14:45", "06:30", "08:45", 
"06:30", "08:45", "06:30", "14:45", "07:30", "17:00", "07:30", 
"16:45", "07:30", "16:45", "07:30", "16:45", "07:30", "16:45", 
"08:45", "23:45", "12:00", "14:15", "13:30", "16:15", "12:30", 
"20:30", "08:00", "10:15")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -80L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), start.end = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Possible outcome:

[image]

Comment: Can you post what the desired output of the analysis on `df` should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not know of any function that already does this, but if you compute the means and standard deviations of the start and end times, you can plot them in a nice little graph:

```
df$time[df$time=="0"]=NA  ## Remove zeroes
df$time.struc = strptime(df$time, format="%H:%M")  ## Compute timestamps
base = strptime("00:00", format="%H:%M")           ## Baseline of current date

m = aggregate(as.double(df$time.struc)-as.double(base), by=list(df$start.end),FUN=mean,na.rm=T)  ## Compute all means
sd = aggregate(df$time.struc, by=list(df$start.end),FUN=sd,na.rm=T)  ## Compute all standard deviations

y = c(1,1,5,5,2,2,4,4,3,3) ## Because of the alphabetic sorting of days

plot(1,pch="",ylim=c(1,5),xlim=c(0,24*3600),main="Start and End times",xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
axis(1,at=c(6*3600,12*3600,18*3600),labels=c("6:00","12:00","18:00"))
axis(2,at=c(1,2,3,4,5),labels=c("Fri","Thu","Wed","Tue","Mon"))
points(m$x,y,col="blue")
arrows(m$x-sd$x,y,m$x+sd$x,y,length=.05,angle=90,code=3,col="blue")
```

The axis and cosmetics of the plot are quite crude at the moment. You might want to embellish it. But that's in essence what you might need to visualize the mean start and end times and their variations.

[image]